# Display the last 30 records with a descending order in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I want to load the last 30 records (messages in this case) from Parse in my UITableView by ordering them by the "created" date. I am able to do that, however, the messages are sorted until the 30th record, the next records are not displayed in my UITableView.

Here is my code :

```
let messagesQuery = PFQuery(className: "Message")
messagesQuery.includeKey("conversation")
messagesQuery.includeKey("author")
messagesQuery.whereKey("conversation", equalTo: conversation)
messagesQuery.orderByAscending("createdAt")
messagesQuery.limit = 30
messagesQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in
}
```

I know I could do use `orderByDescending("createdAt")` instead... However, if I do that, the order of my messages is reversed. I mean, I get the last 30 messages, but the order is reversed (the oldest message appears in the bottom of the conversation and the most recent one, at the top).

So how can I fix that so it displays the last 30 messages, with the most recent at the bottom of my conversation ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set skip value for your query.

```
[messagesQuery setSkip: 0];
```

Reference link
https://parse.com/questions/fetch-all-data-in-a-table-using-pfquery

Answer (score 0):

Try orderByAscending("createdAt")

It also sounds like you want to have a load more button as the user scrolls down towards the bottom of the first 30 messages. You can either have a load more button or an automatic load when the user gets to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sorting them in the result block like this:

```
let messagesQuery = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
    messagesQuery.includeKey("conversation")
    messagesQuery.includeKey("author")
    messagesQuery.whereKey("conversation", equalTo: conversation)
    messagesQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    messagesQuery.limit = 30
    messagesQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in
        if var messages: Array<PFObject> = results {
            for message in messages {
                print(message.createdAt!)
            }
            messages.sortInPlace({ $0.createdAt!.compare($1.createdAt!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })
            print("")
            for message in messages {
                print(message.createdAt!)
            }
        }
    }
```